# Note below figure

Tags: floats, notes

I have a figure and include it in LaTeX using `\includegraphics` in a `\figure` floating environment. The caption is at the top. Basically I would like to have a note below the figure too. I see some entries for tables but not for figures. Please suggest!

Comment: What kind of note do you need? Can you make an example?

Comment: @egreg Just like what lockstep has made below, actually.

Comment: After the `\includegraphics` instruction, be sure to leave a blank line, followed by whatever extra information you wish to provide. If you feel you need to add a bit of vertical separation between the graphic and the subsequent blurb, add an instruction such as `\smallskip` or `\medskip` after the blank one and before the text of the blurb.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [`floatrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package offers the `\floatfoot` macro for notes in addition to a float's `\caption`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
% \centering% default with `floatrow`
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for `\includegraphics`
\caption{A figure}
\floatfoot{A note}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks lockstep. There seems to be a problem now, the (additional) first page of the compiled document has some nonsensical text and there are '%' signs floating around the document. The good news is that there is a note below the figure right where it should be. Any clue how I could rid away that funny text and the '%' signs?

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora Perhaps there's a conflict stemming from the order of packages loaded (you don't load `floatrow` after `hyperref`?). But without a compilable example it's hard to say.

Comment: @locktep, yes. I load it right at the start and things are better now.

Comment: This package is in conflict with float package . I can't import both of them.

Answer (score 50):

Another option is to use the `\caption*` command from the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{A figure}
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for `\includegraphics`
\caption*{A note}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the notes should use separate different formatting than the one used for the captions, a simple definition of a new command using `\captionsetup` will do the job:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand\fnote[1]{\captionsetup{font=small}\caption*{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{A figure}
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for `\includegraphics`
\fnote{A note}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In particular, for controlling the width of the note, use something like `\captionsetup{width=.9\linewidth}`.

Answer (score 7):

Another option:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=YOUR_FIGURE_SCALE]{YOUR_FIGURE.pdf}
    \begin{minipage}{YOUR_SPECIFIED_WIDTH}
    \footnotesize
    \emph{YOUR NOTES}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{YOUR FIGURE CAPTION}
    \label{YOUR_FIGURE_LABEL}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Is `minipage` better than `parbox` for this?

Answer (score 6):

Yet another option using TikZ:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (fig) {
      \includegraphics[YOUR_SETTINGS_HERE]{figures_PAL}
    };
    \node [anchor=north east,color=darkgray,inner sep=0,xshift=-5pt,yshift=-3pt]
      at (fig.south east) {\footnotesize Source: YOUR_SOURCE};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Simplest picture.}
\end{figure}
```

This will result in:

[image: Result]

The benefit of this solution may be that you have to set the dimension only for the graphic. The position of the note follows automatically.

Btw: If the note shall be directly underneath the figure you can change `anchor=north`and the position `at (fig.south)`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option using the `subcaption` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{A figure}
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for `\includegraphics`
\subcaption*{A note}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to make the font smaller for the note?

Comment: @ChinG yes for instance you can use `\subcaption*{\footnotesize{A note}}` or any smaller font size command: `\scriptsize` or `\tiny`