# Note below figure as long as the figure - all centered but note left-aligned

Tags: floats, notes

I have a similar problem with my figure that is scaled, so the footnote/text underneath will be as long as the linewidth not as long as the figure. the figure is in the center and I want a caption above it to be in the center too. But the explanation should stand below the figure and be just as long as the figure (LEFT-aligned). Caption gives me the text above the figure and the text goes outside the figure, too. Here is what I got:

```
% I tried this:
% but the text starts outside the figure \\
\begin{figure}[hp]\caption[]{Balancing Diagnostics Kernel}
\footnotesize\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{Gaus.pdf}
\item\emph{Notes:} This figure provides a graphical illustration of the common trend assumption. And again this figure provides a graphical illustration of the perfect approach for estimating something.
\end{figure}
```

Any idea for figures that are not textwidth but 0.7\textwidth? How do I get an explanation of the figure underneath a scaled figure so that it will be as short as the figure?

This is similar to this problem, but the solutions do not work for scaled figures as it seems. 
[Note below figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56529/note-below-figure)

Comment: Put both the `includegraphics` and your comment below inside a minipage (or parbox) of `0.7\textwidt` width, and use `\textwidth` for the width of the `includegraphics`. Oh, and remove that `\item`.

Comment: The boxhandler package makes captions the exact width of the figure and/or table.

Answer (score 9):

You can put the image and its description into a `minipage` environment. Now you can set the width of image *and* Text below to the same value by just adjusting the `minipage` width. Remark: you have to set the width of the image now to `\linewidth` as `\linewidth` is now the width of the minipage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hp]\caption[]{Balancing Diagnostics Kernel}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.7\linewidth}
%\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Gaus.pdf}
\rule{\linewidth}{10em}
\footnotesize
\emph{Notes:} This figure provides a graphical illustration of the common trend assumption. And again this figure provides a graphical illustration of the perfect approach for estimating something.
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
Some other random text that should fill the whole line like blablabla and the like...
\end{document}
```

[image]