# Decrease vertical space between figure and figure note

Tags: floats, captions

I use the `caption` package to have figure titles above and notes below the figure. I follow [this suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56535/62375) to define a new command that calls the `caption*` command with appropriate settings. However, the space between the figure and the note (another caption) is too large. How can I make it smaller? The `skip` setting only changes the space *after* the note. I tried to specify `abovecaptionskip` directly but that is "undefined in families `caption'".

Here are the relevant code chunks that I use, and below a screenshot what is produced where I highlighted the space I want to decrease.

```latex
# preamble
\usepackage[bf, justification=centering]{caption}
\newcommand\fnote[1]{\captionsetup{font=small,justification=justified}\caption*{#1}}

# figure
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \caption{Comparison of the retirement effect estimate by gender}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure}
  \end{center}
  \fnote{{\it Notes:} The dots ...}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show the code that gives rise to the screenshot you posted. In particular, do please show both the `\caption` and the `\caption*` instructions.

Comment: @Mico you are absolutely right, I edited the question.

Comment: Replace the `center` environment with the `\centering` command. This should help you get rid of the additional vertical white space around the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `center` environment, don't use `\caption*` for the legend below the graphic, and provide the instruction `\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}` to reduce the distance between the caption and the figure.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage[justification=centering,
            labelfont=bf,
            skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\caption{Comparison of the retirement effect estimate by gender}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figfile}

\smallskip\small
\textit{Notes}: The dots represent $\hat{\beta}$, the lines \dots
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't you need [position=above]?

Comment: @JohnKormylo - The `position=above` option isn't needed as long as the `\caption` statement precedes the `\includegraphics` directive; this would seem to be the OP's plan all along.

Comment: I thought it switched \abovecaptionskip and \belowcaptionskip (as is done automatically with tables).